# SQL Server group of databases creation script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a group of databases (database names should be picked from a table in a database (in same instance) in an incremental order). Can anyone help me how to do this?

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT = 1, @Maxid INT = 100, @zid nvarchar(100)     

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @Maxid)
BEGIN
   SELECT @zid = zids
   FROM dbo.list_zid WHERE id = @LoopCounter

   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1

   print @zid  
   end

 DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(50)
SET @DBNAME = '@zid'

CREATE DATABASE @DBNAME
GO
ALTER DATABASE @DBNAME SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
GO
ALTER DATABASE @DBNAME SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

So first the warning you will have to use dynamic SQL on text from a table which can leave you open to all kinds of security issues so do NOT do this if you are not 100% certain of the database values!!!!  Next you have the gist of it, but you cannot just pass the variable to the statment you want to execute.  You have to build the string and then execute the string.  See the example for the logic of where and how to do this.  I have not shown you how to get the DBName from your table what you have written looks like you can figure that out plus if you don't know that you should NOT do this technique yet!

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT = 1, @Maxid INT = 100, @zid nvarchar(100)     

    WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @Maxid)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(50)
        SET @DBNAME = '@zid'

       SELECT @zid = zids
       FROM dbo.list_zid WHERE id = @LoopCounter
       --if you are getting the @zid out of the database I would assume you can also get the name on this query too????



        DECLARE @SQLStatements NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQLStatements = '
    CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBNAME + '
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBNAME + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBNAME + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
    GO'

        EXECUTE (@SQL)


       SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1
           print @zid  
    END
```